# Database agnostic way to say I want a column to be UTF-8 in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I noticed that my MySQL database isn't set to do UTF-8 by default. The `latin1_swedish_ci` collation is selected instead.

So naturally I encountered a user reported bug that my application didn't support special characters. I went and made sure my app handled UTF-8 right, wrote a test, and sure enough it worked fine with in-memory SQLite but not production MySQL.The solution I seem to get from the SQLAlchemy documentation is to pass a collation on my column:

```
 column = db.Column(db.String(500, collation='utf8_general_ci'))
```

Sadly, this causes my unit tests based around SQLite to fail -- utf8_general_ci isn't a supported encoding for SQLite. Its MySQL specific.

SQLite seems fine with UTF-8 without specifying a collation. I can and do test with MySQL, but an in memory SQLite database is a much faster and straight-forward testing option for spot tests. I really prioritize ease of testing, so getting back to testing with SQLite is a big priority for me.

#### Other things I've tried

I've also tried adding

```
charset=utf8&use_unicode=1
```

to my connect string. I've also used `db.Unicode` instead of `db.String`. It seemed to make no difference.

#### Question

Is there a straight-forward and database agnostic way through SQLAlchemy to indicate a column should be encoded with UTF-8?

Comment: Curious! Why don't you change the collations on db and the tables itself?

Comment: If I'm going to do that, I want to do it through SQLAlchemy or through a migration. I'd prefer not to have to do anything other than "db.create_all()"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved my problem is to alter the collation on the table with `__table_args__`:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_collate': 'utf8_general_ci'}

    ...

    column = db.Column(db.String(500))
```

SQLite happily ignores this mysql setting. MySQL picks it up appropriately.